# Need help for explain scala problem

Tags: scala

I have two scala classes (and their Java code when I use `javap -private` to read the class file).

When I use `n` and `d` in the `toString` method, it will generate private member field in class. Why is that? I'm a little confused.

Scala #1:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {

}
```

equivalent from javap:

```
public class com.zjffdu.tutorial.scala.Rational
extends java.lang.Object
implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public com.zjffdu.tutorial.scala.Rational(int, int);
}
```

Scala #2:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  override def toString() = n + "/" + d
}
```

equivalent from javap:

```
public class com.zjffdu.tutorial.scala.Rational
extends java.lang.Object
implements scala.ScalaObject{
    private final int n;
    private final int d;
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public com.zjffdu.tutorial.scala.Rational(int, int);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the value of `n` and `d` needs to be available somehow from inside the `toString` body, right? Otherwise you couldn't use them. Anything could happen between when you construct a new instance and `n` and `d` happen to be on the stack, and when you call `toString`, and `n` and `p` have long disappeared from the stack. So the compiler automatically saves the value in fields — even if you don't declare them as `(private) val`s in your code. The compiler will do so for all constructor variables that are used outside of the constructor of your classes (remember that the constructor of a class is actually the whole body of the class itself, excluding `val` and `def` definitions).

Answer (score 3):

Scala will take constructor arguments, even if not declared `val` or `var` and add them as private fields to a class if they ever need to be used outside of the constructor.

In your case, `toString` could be called long after object creation.  So those parameters need to be stored in the constructed instance.

Comment: Would the same thing happen when it would be `val toString` instead of `def toString`?

Comment: if it was `val toString`, then you'd see a `toString` field instead.

Comment: Yes, sure, but then the private fields for n and d should be gone right?

Comment: soc - indeed, you'd see `toString` instead of `n` and `d`, not as well as them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's more even fun. If you try this:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  override val toString = n + "/" + d
}
```

Then the private vars disappear again!

```
public class Rational extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    private final java.lang.String toString;
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public Rational(int, int);
}
```

The difference is that when you use `d` and `n` in a method, they have to be preserved. If they are not used in a method, only in the constructor (such as `val` initialization), then they don't need to exist as members of each instance. Take a look at the decompiled version of `def toString`:

```
public java.lang.String toString();
  Code:
   0:   new     #10; //class scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #14; //Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_0
   8:   getfield        #19; //Field n:I
   11:  invokevirtual   #23; //Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(I)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringB
uilder;
   14:  ldc     #25; //String /
   16:  invokevirtual   #28; //Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collectio
n/mutable/StringBuilder;
   19:  aload_0
   20:  getfield        #30; //Field d:I
   23:  invokestatic    #36; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   26:  invokevirtual   #28; //Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collectio
n/mutable/StringBuilder;
   29:  invokevirtual   #38; //Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   32:  areturn
```

See lines 8 and 20?